# Xdebug and PHP not working on my server

Tags: php, linux, apache, lamp, xdebug

I've had xdebug and php configured many times in the passed, but going back over my old notes, is failing to help me get it configured again.

I have done the following:

1. Installed `LAMP`
2. Installed `php5-xdebug`
3. Restarted apache `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
4. The `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/xdebug.ini` now looks like this:

*xdebug.ini*

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
```

I create a php file which just contains `phpinfo();` and when I load that page in the browser, I don't get an xdebug section as normal which contains all the xdebug details like

```
xdebug.collect
xdebug.dump
xdebug.profiler
```

etc etc.

What have I don't wrong this time round?

```
The OS is Ubuntu 12.04
PHP version is 5.3.10
Apache version is 2.2.22
Xdebug version is 2.1.0-1
```

Comment: Did you try formatting xdebug.ini properly and checking if it is included in overall configuration?

Comment: Text looks ok in normal text editor.

Comment: why `zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so` ? I have `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so` (note the +lfs) (I have same os)

Comment: Did you check /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so for existence? Did you restart the server after you installed xdebug?

Comment: What ini files are loaded, is xdebug there? Is the `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` even inspected? Is `xdebug.ini` readable for your webserver? Does PHP log any startup errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go through the following steps:

- Verify that the .so file really exists at that path (copy/paste and `ls`)
- Use the output of `phpinfo()` to tell you which .ini files are being parsed, is yours included? Is the `apache2/*.ini` dir being included?
- Check the apache error log for any errors that might have occurred at restart

Answer (score 3):

After i updated from PHP 5.3 to 5.5 i was seeing this error:

> Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: 
>   /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file:
>   No such file or directory

To fix i changed the path to xdebug.so in

> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

from

> /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so

to

> /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so

Answer (score 0):

Do a sudo find / -name 'xdebug.so'

and copy the location of this file in
xdebug.ini
and 
php.ini file